# How to define distribution, given probability generating function?

Tags: distributions, probability-generating-fn

Given some probability generating function $G_X:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

Since

$$P_X(k)=\frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$

then how does one define the distribution $P_X(k)$ in practice?
The difficulty is the $k$ parameter, which may be, e.g. $\mathbb{Z_+}=\{0,1,2,...\}$.

Surely one cannot calculate the derivative at every $k$?

Comment: What is the question, really?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is really the relation $P(k) = G^{(k)}(0) \, / \, k!$ that you quoted.

Sometimes it's relatively easy to evaluate the derivative – especially if you have $G$ as a power series, in which case you just read off the $k$th term. But in general, a generating function is not a particularly convenient form for evaluating the mass function, but instead a useful tool to do other things with.